# Need help accessing webbrowser control from form1

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i need to know one thing where i am stuck..

I have form1 which is my main form. I have a panel in that and I created form2.

I added form2 into my panel like below

```
Form2 frm = new Form2();
frm.TopLevel = false;
frm.Show();
panel1.Controls.Add(frm);
```

My form 2 has a webbrowser control in it. I need to access that webbrowser control from Form1. How can i do it??

Comment: Did you try `frm.WebBrowserControl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the protection of the webbrowser control to public, or create a public property that returns your webbrowser control.

Then you can reference it with

`frm.MyWebBrowserControl`

Comment: holy cow..that did it for me.. I can access now.. thanks mate!!

Answer (score 0):

Can use [Forms.Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx) property to access all controls present on the form.

And here can find `WebBrowserControl` among them:

```
var browser = form.Controls.OfType<WebBrowser>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Here I used [OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/bb360913.aspx) method of [Control.ControlCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.aspx) type.